# MGTwitterEngine currentNode is unavailable

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, xcode7, twitter-oauth, mgtwitterengine

I am using the MGTwitterEngine in an iOS app that was built by a third party. I have taken over development but have limited experience in objective c.

I am getting an error: `'currentNode' is unavailable.`

This is in the `MGTwitterXMLParser.m` file. The interface has a weak link like this:

```
__weak NSMutableDictionary *currentNode;
```

I had to add the `libOAuth.a` file because it was missing and I am wondering if this is the cause. Do I need a certain version of libOAuth?

The weird part is that it worked with the new `libOAuth.a` until I updated XCode to the latest version which is 7.3. Is anyone having issues with MGTwitterEngine in 7.3?

UPDATE:

In XCode (I was compiling in AppCode) I now see that it says, "Declaration uses __weak, but ARC is disabled."

This is in MGTwitterXMLParser:
__weak NSMutableDictionary *currentNode;

My project has ARC enabled and I don't see any way to set ARC for the MGTwitterEngine or any individual files. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the answer was simple once I understood the problem. I simply needed to discard the __weak for the NSMutableDictionary and it compiled.

Still need to test Twitter and look for any memory leaks. Also, not sure how the app ever compiled before with a __weak reference in a non-ARC file.